# MySQL skip first 10 results

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to have the first 10 result from a SELECT query skipped?
I'd like it to work something like LIMIT.

Comment: all answers here are missing an ORDER BY clause. SQL tables have no default order, and without an explicit ORDER BY there's no way to tell wich are the first 10 results to skip

Answer (score 170):

Use LIMIT with two parameters. For example, to return results 11-60 (where result 1 is the first row), use:

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 50
```

For a solution to return all results, see [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results/2827041#2827041).

Comment: What if some rows are deleted between the number you've mentioned.

Comment: It's just row's not id's. So no problem will cause.

Answer (score 125):

There is an OFFSET as well that should do the trick:

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: more easy to understand than `limit 10,10`

Answer (score 64):

[OFFSET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: I think ```SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 50``` approach is better if our intension is just pagination.

Answer (score 39):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
> ```

Obviously, you should replace `95` by `10`. The large number they use is 2^64 - 1, by the way.

Comment: Wow, this makes the query take a huge ammount of time. Weird recommendation for their manual.

Answer (score 7):

LIMIT allow you to skip any number of rows. It has **two** parameters, and first of them - how many rows to skip

Comment: and if there is no second parameter, then the first parameter is not the number to skip, but the number to take.  This is a poor design in my opinion.  I stick with OFFSET.

Answer (score 5):

To skip first 10 rows use OFFSET 10, but LIMIT is also required,

If you want to get all the rows and only skip first 10 rows try using a big number like 999999999 or as per your choice

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 999999 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table where id not in (select id from table limit 10)
```

where `id` be the key in your table.

Comment: This is useful and fast to do, for impala and other databases where the limit with offset requires an order argument which is not always desirable.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 50``` try this approach

Comment: Nice approach, not working in MariaDB as of now : `This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Answer (score -7):

If your table has ordering by id, you could easily done by:

```
select * from table where id > 10
```

Comment: You are assuming that the first 10 records are all still there. Even if they are, if one is deleted at any point in the future that would break your method.

Comment: assumed that you didn't understand the question.