# Use PHP while() only to return the first few values.

Tags: php, pagination, while-loop

I am using PHP while() to fetch the results of a database query.

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array( $galleryresult )) { // show the results };
```

However, I would like to paginate the results if they exceed a certain number of entries. So for example if there are more than 12 entries returned, only the first 12 will be shown.

1) How can I adapt while() so only the first 12 entries are returned on the first page.

2) Then how can I adapt while() so the 13th-24th result are returned on the second page and so on.

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* API anymore. It is being deprecated by the community. It's highly insecure and inefficient. Use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL skip first 10 results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the query such that only 12 entries are in the result set. That way you do not need to modify the while loop.

Add a parameter to the URL, that tells the script the offset that should be used in the SQL query.

Create a query that counts the total number of results. Use this to determine how many pages should be displayed in the pager.

Comment: This works. I retrieve the page from the URL (using $_GET). Seperately I save the number of entries per page (e.g. 12) in a variable. Then I just multiply the number of entries in a page by the current page to determine which index I am on.

So for example;
$imagestoshow = "12";
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
 $pageindex = $_GET['p'] * $imagestoshow; 
}

Then just add this to the SQL query:
limit " .$pageindex. "," .$imagestoshow;