# MySQL Delete with Limit

Tags: php, mysql

This seems very simple, but it's failing.  All I want to do is delete all but the first row using the code below.

```
$sql    = "DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news WHERE course_id = $course_id LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
```

If I do this...

```
$sql    = "SELECT news_id FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news WHERE course_id = $course_id LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['news_id'] . '<br>';
}
```

All news_ids are echoed except the first one.  Why is the delete statement **not** working when the same statement for select **is** working?

Comment: What determines what is the first row ?

Comment: Also, that's not the right syntax for LIMIT in a DELETE statement - you just need to include one integer for the maximum number of rows to delete: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: The "LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615" part is supposed to be skipping the first row, then deleting everything else.  I got this idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results

Comment: Whatever you do, I advice defining `ORDER BY news_id ASC` so that it will always be sorted the way you think it is sorted. I have never tried to delete like that, so I can't give much help for that. You could possibly select the first news_id, then delete `WHERE course_id = $course_id AND news_id != $news_id`

Comment: @JohnBovey - that question is about SELECT, not DELETE. The two syntaxes are similar, but not identical.

Comment: do you need to delete all rows except one, no matter what, or there's a particular row that is the first?

Comment: news_id is an auto incrementing field.  So, basically the lowest news_id for a particular course would be the "first" one and it should not be deleted.  Does that help define this problem a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete statement is not working because of incorrect syntax near the limit keyword...you cannot do `LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615`...`LIMIT` must be followed by a single number when used with `DEELTE`

Reference: [DELETE MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Only in a SELECT statement can you have `LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615` clause

Reference: [SELECT MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

What you can do alternatively is find the course_id of the first row you want deleted, (and hopefully if the table is set up correctly and it is a primary key for the table and auto increments), do something like the below:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news 
        WHERE course_id >=".COURSE_ID_YOU_WANT_DELETED.";
```

Or this works as well:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news 
        WHERE course_id !=".COURSE_ID_YOU_WANT.";
```

Comment: The examples do not equal the OP's code. And the also do not exclude all but the first row.

Comment: I can see this working by first selecting the "first" news_id as I described in the comment above.  I'll hold off on selecting this as the answer until others have had a chance to reply though.  Thanks!

Comment: After some tweaking, I got your idea working.  If anyone is interested, the code I ended up using was `$sql    = "SELECT news_id FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news WHERE course_id = $course_id ORDER BY news_id asc LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  
  
  $sql = "DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news WHERE course_id = $course_id AND news_id!='".$row['news_id']."'"; 
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);`

Answer (score 4):

Like @Sabashan said LIMIT in DELETE statement only allows one parameter.

If you want to exclude the 1st row, use something like:

```
DELETE FROM tnews WHERE course_id = $course_id 
AND primary_key NOT IN 
(SELECT * FROM (
SELECT primary_key FROM tnews ORDER BY something LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0))
```

The inner SELECT picks up the records to exclude. 
The outer SELECT solves the problem that you cannot select from the same table that you're deleting from. 
Because the inner SELECT is enclosed by the outer select MySQL materializes the result in a temp table and uses that instead of rerunning the query for every delete (which MySQL does not allow).

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but it's not working.  I have

`$sql    = "DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news WHERE course_id = $course_id AND primary_key NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT primary_key FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."news ORDER BY news_id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0))";
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);`

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to replace the ’primary_key’ placeholder with whatever field name you pk has. If there really was a keyword like that, I'd written it in caps as per convention.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the id of the first row and do a

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id != id_found
```

or find the ids you have to delete and

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (ids_found)
```