# Iterate trougth database table rows C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have in my database a table called students that have the number and name, address....
I have a form where I load all information for one student at a a time , and I have a next button and a back button.
How can I iterate to the next row (or previous row) in mysql (to be able to see the info of the next student) ?
I tried to use the primary key (auto increment) to iterate and when I want to see the next record I add 1 to the id or subtract 1 to see the previous record.
But if one record is deleted it will show an empty record. 
Can you point me in the rigth direction?
I´m using WinForms
Sorry about my english..

```
            string config = "server=localhost; userid = root; database = databaseName";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(config);

            MySqlDataReader reader = null;
            string query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = " + id; //id is the primary Key (auto increment)

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                string studentName = (string)reader["studentName"];

                string studentNum = (string)reader["studentNum"];

                tbstudentName.Text = Convert.ToString(studentName);
                tbstudentNum.Text = Convert.ToString(studentNum);                   

                .....
            }
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be calling the database each time you want to view the next record. Try reading all the data into a List.

I am not sure what you are using.. WinForms? WPF?

If WinForms you will need to do something like this.

```
    public class Student
    {//First create a class to hold your data in
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Num { get; set; }
    }

public class MyForm : Form
{
    int Index = 0;
    List<Student> FormData { get; set; }

    void GetData()
    {
    //This will hold all your data in memory so you do not have to make a database call each and every "iteration"
    List<Student> dbData = new List<Student>();

    string config = "server=localhost; userid = root; database = databaseName";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(config);

        MySqlDataReader reader = null;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM students";

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Student newStudent = new Student();

            newStudent.Name = (string)reader["studentName"];

            newStudent.Num = (string)reader["studentNum"];
            //Add data to the list you created
            dbData.Add(newStudent);          

            .....
        }
        con.Close();

        //set the Form's list equal to the one you just populated
        this.FormData = dbData;
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        //If winforms
        tbstudentName.Text = FormData[Index].Name;
        tbstudentNum.Text = FormData[Index].Num;

        //If wpf you will have to use view models and bind your data in your XAML but I am assuming you are using
        //winforms here.
    }

    private void NextRecord()
    {    //If you reached the end of the records then this will prevent IndexOutOfRange Exception
        if (Index < FormData.Count - 1)
        {
            Index++;
            BindData();
        }
    }

    private void PreviousRecord()
    {
        if (Index != 0)
        {
            Index--;
            BindData();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the above scenario will get it working quickly; however, there are better ways in doing this that would help you when you need to alter that data. I would recommend WinForms Binding. You can check it out here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i get an error in this line  if (Index < FormData.Count - 1)  saying NullReferenceException was unhandled

Comment: Can you update your answer with all of the code you are using? That probably means your `FormData` is null and was never set. I'll check it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the next you can write:

```
select * from students where id > @id
order by id asc
limit 1
```

And to get previous

```
select * from students where id < @id
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Designed to quick one-time read.

If you want to hold the data, you need to fill memory arrays.
the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements it very well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to think a little different.

Getting `id+1` you are being very careless.. Even identity, the Id can be another value and you will get an Exception.. I suppose that you don't want it.

You will need to Adjust your logic to return lines with `top` or, in mysql, `limit`  statement..

This will be easy using lambda to use `.Take()` and `Skip()` methods...
You also can use the limit parameter to pass throug this sample.. you can understand..

[MySQL skip first 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results)

Hope it helps.