# Select all rows except top row in Maria DB

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

How do I return all rows from a table except the first row. Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM article  where article_no 
NOT IN
(SELECT * FROM article   order by article_no  limit 1)
```

The up given SQL query throws an error:

> This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Try `NOT IN (SELECT article_no FROM article   order by article_no  limit 1)`

Comment: shows error :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: error near WHAT?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT IN (SELECT * FROM article order by article_no limit 1)'  @RiggsFolly

Comment: For heavens sake ___Thats your original code___ Not the amendment I suggested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL skip first 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results)

Comment: Use the OFFSET keyword. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery must select only the column you need for comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE article_no NOT IN (
    SELECT article_no
    FROM article
    ORDER BY article_no
    LIMIT 1
)
```

The above query will work in MySQL, but not in MariaDB, which [doesn't currently support `LIMIT` in subqueries](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/subquery-limitations/). I would rewrite the subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM article
WHERE article_no NOT IN (SELECT MIN(article_no) FROM article)
```

Comment: Not that I am overly bothered, but that is kinda.. well very very very like my comment

Comment: Hmmm my comment has been there for 9 minutes before your answer was posted! I guess you must be a slow typer

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I read the question, but not the comments. I wrote an answer because there wasn't one already. I then read your comments and noticed that you'd recommended the same thing. I can delete my answer if you'd rather put yours.

Comment: Like i said "Am I bovered"

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Thanks the amendment but that didn't actually solved the use of **limit** function in my sub query

Answer (score 1):

This skips the row with the lowest value of `article_no`:

```
SELECT *
    FROM article
    ORDER BY article_no ASC
    LIMIT 999999999
    OFFSET 1;
```

Perhaps you want `DESC` (instead of `ASC`) to skip the highest value?

Be aware that `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is a very inefficient construct.

Comment: This doesn't work, as `OFFSET` cannot be used without `LIMIT` in MySQL or MariaDB

Comment: @Sonny - Oops.  I added `LIMIT` with a huge value to make it work.