# AngularJS code hangs browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am calling a Web Service which returns around 3000 records as data entries as HTML response & i am trying to read this response using angularJS.

Below is my AngularJS code i am using to call the service

```
angular.module('tabApp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('TabController', ['$scope', 'HttpService', function($scope, HttpService) {
        $scope.tab = 0;

        $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
              $scope.tab = newTab;

            $scope.loading = true;
            HttpService.CallService('Service.php?id='+newTab,newTab, function (data) {
                             $scope.myText = data;
                             $('.count').show();
                             $("[id^=searchg]").show();
                             $('.results').show();
            });
        };


        $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
          return $scope.tab === tabNum;

        };

        $scope.setTab1 = function(newTab1){
            $scope.tab = newTab1;
            $('.loaderImage').hide();
      };



        $scope.isSet1 = function(tabNum){
            return $scope.tab === tabNum;
          };
}])

.service('HttpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
        $rootScope.loading = true;
        return {
            CallService: function (url,tabnum, callback) {                   
                $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {id: tabnum}})
                    .success(function (data, status) {                            
                        $('.loaderImage').hide();
                        callback(data, status);
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                    $('.loaderImage').hide();
                        callback(status);
                    });                 
            } 
        }
    }]);
```

My problem is the browser hangs if the returned records are more than 1500. Please advise on how i can improve this.

Update:

My html code looks like this

```
<div ng-show="isSet(1)">
        <div id=matches  style="display:none"></div>
        <input type=text id=searchg placeholder="Type to search..." style="display:none" />
          <p class="preload" ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: are you processing/displaying all 3000 records at once?

Comment: add pagination to your client, and fetch 10 or 20 records from your api. Or you can lazy load, fetch 10 records when user scroll page.

Comment: You may try to precede the binding with `::` to encourage one-way binding. This may help reducing the number of watchers, making your HTML faster.

Comment: @GiteshPurbia , Where do i need to add this pagination. Can you give me an example for this?.thanks

Comment: first you add skip and limit to your fetch query, where you send only 10 record at a time and then pass skip and limit in every call which you call at the every scroll.

Comment: look at this example, you will get idea, https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html

Comment: @GiteshPurbia, The above example looks different from my case. In my case the webservice is returning all records at once.

Comment: It's fetching records from mysql

Comment: yes, so in you select query add skip and limit, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results

Comment: I tried the limit solution & it worked fine. I thought there may be a solution available in angularJS for this

Comment: Fetching 3000 records is going to take time no matter what your implementation is. It takes time at the database level, so why won't it take time at the application level? You must reduce the records fetched, or fetch in batches.

Answer (score 2):

As we can see it is the bulky data which you are trying to bind. In Future, it could be more bulky.
You should use the server side pagination and get only the number of records, what your pagination is.

Here is the `JSFiddle` link for the reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/dwahlin/3Kewg/

Hope this helps! CHEERS TO CODE! :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohit Dixit suggested, you should prefer to do server side paging and request only active page records.

I would advise you to use smart table library for this. [Here](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) is the official website for same. They support paging(both server side and client side), filter and sorting in one go.

Please note that there are many library available for this purpose but I am suggesting this as I am using it from past few years.