# Skip First Record From MySQL Result

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have data with the same id in the table. For example, I have 3 data with the id `X` now whenever I query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = X ORDER BY id
```

It will return me all 3 data having an id `X`
Now I am looking for a solution to skip the first row from data which comes in the result.

I looked up in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results) and also [LIMIT & OFFSET](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html), but I did not get any proper solution.
How can I skip the first row?

Comment: What was wrong with the things you tried with OFFSET? And why do you want to skip randomly one of the rows?

Comment: Besides using `OFFSET`, you could just read in some number of records and then skip the first row in your PHP script.

Comment: I just wants to skip first data from sql result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL skip first 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check this out:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = X ORDER BY id LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;
```

[Here is a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/64390)

In my Fiddle, there is 3 records with similar id(1). After executing query, output showing 2 records by skipping first record(from a total of 3)

Comment: Can you do a fiddle to check.

Comment: Please correct this to : SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = X ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;