# How to select n th row to last record sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a situation where i have to show the first 9 rows with domain name of email and no of occurences of the email and the 10th row as the sum of the remaining domains and show it as others.

What i have done .

I have succesfully get the different domains and their occurrences using the below query

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as domain,
       COUNT(*) as C
FROM newsletter_recipient
where LENGTH(email) > 0
GROUP BY (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1))
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Current Result

```
domain           C
------------------------    
gmail           12  
dddd            2   
mmmmm           2   
dsf             2   
aaaa            1   
bbbb            1   
ccc             1   
yopmail         1   
yahoo           1   
dde             1   
rfg             1   
eedd            1   
dfdg            1   
sad             1   
dfdf            1   
sfd             1   
web             1
```

Expected Result

```
domain           C
------------------------    
gmail           12  
dddd            2   
mmmmm           2   
dsf             2   
aaaa            1   
bbbb            1   
ccc             1   
yopmail         1   
yahoo           1
others          8
```

Hope Someone could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum < 10 THEN domain ELSE 'Others' END) as domain,
       SUM(c)
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1), '.', 1) as domain,
             COUNT(*) as C,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM newsletter_recipient
      WHERE LENGTH(email) > 0
      GROUP BY domain
     ) d
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN seqnum < 10 THEN domain ELSE 'Others' END)
ORDER BY SUM(c) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case when expression` -

```
SELECT case when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1)) 
not in ('gmail','dddd','mmmmm','dsf','aaaa','bbbb','ccc','yopmail','yahoo') then 'Other'
else (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as domain,
       COUNT(*) as C
FROM newsletter_recipient
where LENGTH(email) > 0
GROUP BY case when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1)) 
not in ('gmail','dddd','mmmmm','dsf','aaaa','bbbb','ccc','yopmail','yahoo') then 'Other'
else (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1))
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: ohh..I cant just hardcode the mailclients in the not in  since they are dynamic.:-(

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following

```
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as domain,
     COUNT(*) as C
     FROM newsletter_recipient
     WHERE LENGTH(email) > 0
     GROUP BY (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1))
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
SELECT 
     IF(rn < 10, domain, 'others') AS domain_name,
     SUM(c) AS count
FROM (
     SELECT domain, c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn FROM cte
) T
GROUP BY domain_name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b631a050eb7705ce5682b5839a92907)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with a union first 10 + others:

```
SELECT * from (

SELECT 
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),
            '.',
            1)) AS domain,
    COUNT(*) AS C
FROM
     newsletter_recipient
WHERE
    LENGTH(email) > 0
GROUP BY (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),
        '.',
        1))
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
Limit 10) as FIRST_10

UNION 

SELECT 'others', sum(ALL_OTHERS.C) from (

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS C
FROM
    newsletter_recipient
WHERE
    LENGTH(email) > 0
GROUP BY (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),
        '.',
        1))
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
Limit 11,18446744073709551615
) as ALL_OTHERS
```

18446744073709551615 : Big enough to skip first 10 and ensure to retrieve all of the others , see : [MySQL skip first 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results/2827041#2827041)