# How to select all rows, skipping the first 10 by using LIMIT and OFFSET?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Let's assume the table has 110 rows. The following skips the first 10 rows and returns the other 100:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10, 100
```

Is there a way to replace `100` by *whatever is left*?

Desired pseudo-code:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10, *
```

Comment: Time for a trip to the manual 'The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:

Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.

Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Doesn't MySQL users (sometimes) do LIMIT 10, 10000000, or similar?

Comment: Yes, just use some unfeasibly large number for the second argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL skip first 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results)

Answer (score 2):

[SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT (SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME) OFFSET 10;
```

Not sure about the execution time though.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

This is returning the number of available rows

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from (
Select *,Row_Number() Over(Order By ID ASC) RN From Table 
) as vw
where RN >10
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.